# Update Column from Columns within same table using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, correlated-subquery

I’m trying to update an email address value from users first- and lastname within the same table.

Pattern for generated Mail: `<Firstname>.<Lastname>@test.org`

Example Table “Persons”:

```
 Firstname  Lastname     email 

 Henley     Figueroa     none@none.com
 Samina     Morrison     none@none.com 
 Dev        Rowe         none@none.com
```

Wished result for table “Persons”:

```
Firstname Lastname    email 

Henley    Figueroa    Henley.Figueroa@test.org
Samina    Morrison    Samina.Morrison@test.org
Dev       Rowe        Dev.Rowe@test.org
```

SQL Code

```
UPDATE Persons
SET 
  email = (SELECT FirstName || "." || LastName ||"@"||"test.org" FROM Persons)
```

Actual result for table “Persons”:

```
Firstname   Lastname      email 

Henley      Figueroa      Henley.Figueroa@test.org
Samina      Morrison      Henley.Figueroa@test.org
Dev         Rowe          Henley.Figueroa@test.org
```

Only the first record of the returned result table is used over and over. Why?

If I ommit the SELECT:

```
UPDATE Persons
SET
    email = FirstName || "." || LastName ||"@"||"test.org"
```

I get the expected result.

Referring to your answers, I'm extending my question with an example of two tables. One with only names, the second for mail addresses.

Table Persons:

| ID* | Firstname | Lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Henley | Figueroa |
| 2 | Samina | Morrison |
| 3 | Dev | Rowe |

Table Addresses:

| ID* | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | wrong@wrong.ng |
| 2 | wrong@wrong,ng |
| 3 | wrong@wro.ng |

```
UPDATE Addresses
SET email = (SELECT Firstname ||"."|| Lastname || "@test.org" 
             FROM Persons WHERE Persons.id = Addresses.id)
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6c07b0f1a47e21482b607fa5fa0ed15d)

Here the UPDATE with SET and SELECT works (Every person gets a unique mail address). Shouldn’t I get the same problem here?
From the output of SELECT I see that I get again (as expected) three records.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right syntax for your problem.  So the question is why does this not do what you want?

```
UPDATE Persons
    SET email = (SELECT FirstName || "." || LastName ||"@"||"test.org" 
                 FROM Persons
                );
```

In fact, this *should* produce an error in any SQL engine -- although SQLite can be a bit lax about such errors.  Why?  The `SET` is expecting a *single* value.  This code has a subquery that returns *three* values.

Note:  The [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9a910dca48c898c1ca2afd31f3052179) does show that SQLite accepts this syntax.  Argggh!  You can switch this to Postgres to see the error.  With some modifications, to the create code you could also see the same error (subquery returns more than one row) using SQL Server or Oracle or just about any database.

Apparently, SQLite is just arbitrarily choosing one of those values -- the one that it first encounters.  And this is the same value for all three rows.

You already know that a subquery is not correct here.  You have the correct code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, they gave me good hints and let me wondering again, so I extended my question.  For me it’s still not clear why in my second example the subquery, which gets three records back works…

Comment: @Seven . . . It is not clear to me either.  I would consider this a bug.  I'm guessing someone thinks this is a "feature" (and one not shared by other databases or the SQL standard).  Why that would be I cannot really imagine.  It is simple enough to add `limit 1`.

Answer (score 1):

From [Subquery Expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subquery_expressions):

> A SELECT statement enclosed in parentheses is a subquery. All types of
> SELECT statement, including aggregate and compound SELECT queries
> (queries with keywords like UNION or EXCEPT) are allowed as scalar
> subqueries. **The value of a subquery expression is the first row of
> the result from the enclosed SELECT statement**. The value of a
> subquery expression is NULL if the enclosed SELECT statement returns
> no rows.

So the value you get by the subquery is the first row of the rows returned.

Of course, you don't need the `SELECT` statement.
This is a simple `UPDATE` statement that involves only **the values of the columns of the current row**:

```
UPDATE Persons
SET email = FirstName || '.' || LastName || '@' || 'test.org'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=30eefb5dc177510639c169b9a62a0822).
Results:

| Firstname | Lastname | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Henley | Figueroa | Henley.Figueroa@test.org |
| Samina | Morrison | Samina.Morrison@test.org |
| Dev | Rowe | Dev.Rowe@test.org |

For the 2nd query with the 2 tables:

> Shouldn’t I get the same problem here?

No, because the subquery is a [correlated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) subquery, which returns for each row in the table `Addresses` only 1 row (provided there are no duplicate ids in `Persons`), the row which matches the condition `Persons.id = Addresses.id`.
If there is no row that matches the condition then it will return `NULL`.